# Save and Load an ArrayList Under Strings?

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I'm using PrintWriter to save an ArrayList to a file. I'm using more than one ArrayList. Is it possible to save and load an ArrayList under a string? Let's say I want to use the strings below:

```
Admins
- ArrayList here.
- ArrayList here.
Bans
-
-
IPs
-
-
```

Above this what I want the file saved to look like.

I'm using a scanner to load the ArrayList. Is it possible to load the ArrayList under the strings above?

Below is some of the code I'm using to save the ArrayList.

```
    public static void save()
    {
        String adminsConfigs1 = killAdmins.toString();

        try 
        {   
            PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(FILE));

            pw1.write(adminsConfigs1);

            pw1.close();
          }
}
```

Comment: Eh, yes, I guess? I don't think your example is really helpful. How about including your code?

Comment: What sort of data are the items in your ArrayList? Strings? Integers? Objects?

Comment: @Veluria It's a very simple code using PrintWriter and Scanners. I'll add some code.

Comment: You can't just print (using `toString()`) an ArrayList with arbitrary data and expect that the resulting text would be useful to reload the data back into a new ArrayList, you need to use something more complex like serialization, or protobuf, etc...

Comment: @morgano The data stored inside the ArrayList is Bukkit's Players.  Also, that's not my full code. I am using serialization in the ArrayList. This is just the saving of the ArrayList. The ArrayList works fine, I've tested it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact solution, but you should get the idea:

Your save could look something like:

```
ArrayList<String>killAdmins; //or whatever
File saved_items = new File("saved.txt")
try {   
     PrintWriter pw1 = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(saved_items));
        for(String item_to_save : killAdmins){
          pw1.append(item_to_save + "\n");
        } 
        pw1.append("-----------")
        pw1.close();
      }
```

Then to load your could do something like:

```
File saved_items = new File("saved.txt")
BufferedReader stream_in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(saved_items));
String line;
ArrayList<String> list;
while((line = stream_in.readline)!=null){
       if(line.contains("-----------")){
              break;
        }
       list.add(line.trim());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use GSON library to store an object to a string and therefore to a txt file. It is simple to use and you need only a few lines of code to get going.